# I have data stored in Perl array. How do I convert them into JavaScript array using JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, json, perl

Here is a similar example of what I am trying to do:

```
@name = qw (Sam Tom John Mike Andrea);
@scores = qw (92 80 59 83 88);
```

I need to store these array as JavaScript so I can make useful graphs on the web page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send a JSON response from a Perl CGI program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435442/how-can-i-send-a-json-response-from-a-perl-cgi-program)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to keep them as separate arrays, stick references to them in a hash first:

```
my %data = ( names => \@names, scores => \@scores );
```

Then use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to serialize the data structure to JSON, e.g.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @names  = qw (Sam Tom John Mike Andrea);
my @scores = qw (92 80 59 83 88);

my %data = ( names => \@names, scores => \@scores );

my $json = encode_json \%data;

print $json
```

Output:

```
{"names":["Sam","Tom","John","Mike","Andrea"],"scores":["92","80","59","83","88"]}
```

Comment: This makes sense but here is what I have.

Comment: Then I suggest asking a new question about what you are *actually* trying to do, and what you are having trouble with. If you just make up an irrelevant question, the answer probably won't help you.