# Enable CORS to get content on another home server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, webserver

I am trying to get a little script running on one of my home servers.
My webserver (192.168.1.100) serves a website which has to get information from another server (192.168.1.225). This server generates a plaintext file.
However, the script on my website refuses to load information from any other website because of the 'Same-Origin-Rule'. The only possibilities to solve this problem are either to place both files on the same server or to enable CORS. Former is not possible, so I did a little research about latter. I found that enabling CORS is done by adding the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", so I did this, without solving the problem.

That means, I have the following:

`Server A (192.168.1.225) generates and serves a plaintext file on every GET request.`

`Server B (192.168.1.110) serves a simple interface and displays information received by Server B trough javascript.`

`Server B serves the following file:`

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
  <style> /*...*/ </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>This is the parsed content of "some_file.cgi"</p>
  <script>
   function http_get(url) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
   }

   function parse_page(page) {
    // Parse some content
   }

   var page = parse_page( http_get('http://192.168.1.225/foo/bar/some_file.cgi') );
   document.write(page);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I enable CORS and why is it not working the way I did?

`TL;DR: Client-Side javascript served by 192.168.1.100 needs to get the content of 192.168.1.225/foo/bar/some_file.cgi.`

Comment: Which browser are you using? What error message are you getting after including the `Access-control-allow-origin` header? If you're using Chrome can you confirm whether the correct header is set in the response?

Comment: I am using Firefox. I have no clue how to set the response header on Server B. The error message I get is `"Cross-Origin-Request blocked: Same-Origin-Rule denies access to read the external resource on 192.168.1.225/foo/bar/some_file.cgi. This can be solved by either moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."` (Not the exact words, translated this from german to english)

Comment: That would suggest the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not being set correctly. How are you doing this?

Comment: Yeah that might be it ;) However, I don't know how to set it on the server.

Comment: you can serve it as jsonp instead of plain text, which might be easier to do than modifying the headers.

Comment: If you're using `apache` with the `mod_headers` module just add the following to the `.htaccess` file:```<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>```

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the correct response headers, haven't used CGI/Perl in quite a while, but according to http://enable-cors.org/server_cgi.html it should be something like:

```
print header(
  -type => 'text/plain',
  -content_location => 'sometextfile.txt',
  -access_control_allow_origin => '*',
);
```

You could also just do a jsonp request, which you can do without doing a cors setup.

Follow the steps from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435442/how-can-i-send-a-json-response-from-a-perl-cgi-program), but instead of just:

```
print $json_text;
```

do

```
print 'someFunction('.$json_text.');';
```

And in your JS

```
function someFunction(data){
    //handle the data
}

function http_get(url) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
http_get('http://192.168.1.225/foo/bar/some_file.cgi');
```

Like I said earlier haven't used CGI/Perl in awhile so you will have to check the syntax etc.